# Using Java LocalDateTime to set AlarmManager vs Using Calander

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar, android-calendar

I am writing an alarm scheduling class. The previous classes I wrote used Calendar to set the alarm.

I have changed over to the new Java DateTime api using Three Ten Backport.

I was previously setting the single shot alarms by getting the time in milliseconds of the calendar like this:

```
    // For the different versions of operating system set off a single shot alarm
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                alarmCalander.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalander.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    } else {
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalander.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    }
```

You can see I used the get time in milliseconds on the Calendar like this:

```
alarmCalander.getTimeInMillis()
```

Now instead of a calendar I have a LocalDateTime

but I am not seeing any way of getting the time in milliseconds for a LocalDateTime,  only nano seconds.

Would you just convert it back to milliseconds or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to convert your `LocalDateTime` (LDT) into an `Instant` before you could read timestamp-related information from it. There's multiple ways of achieving this:

1. Call `toInstant(ZoneOffset)` in your `LDT` instance. Mind you, you'd have to pass in a matching `ZoneOffset` according to your `LDT` otherwise you might get an incorrect `Instant`.

   For example, say your `LDT` was calculated at UTC:

   ```
    LocalDateTime ldt = /* ... */
    Instant i = ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Long millis = i.toEpochMilli();
   ```
2. Convert your `LDT` instance to `ZonedDateTime` passing in correct zone ID then use it to produce an `Instant` without the need of `ZoneOffset`:

   ```
    LocalDateTime ldt = /* ... */
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    Instant i = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    Long millis = i.toEpochMilli();
   ```

Comment: The zone offset does not seem to be optional

Comment: My bad. I'll look more into it.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try